# not all code return a value

Tags: path, return

```
private static long CalculateScore(byte chances, long millisec) { int score; byte num1 = chances++; byte num2 = (byte)10; byte num3 = (byte)10; switch (Program.currLevelIndex) { case (byte)7: num2 = (byte)10; break; case (byte)11: num2 = (byte)20; break; case (byte)15: num2 = (byte)40; break; }

    if ((int)chances >= 1 && (int)chances <= 3)
        num1 = (byte)40;
    else if ((int)chances >= 4 && (int)chances <= 6)
        num1 = (byte)20;
    else if ((int)chances > 7)
        num1 = (byte)10;
    if (millisec > 480000L)
        num3 = (byte)10;
    else if (millisec >= 240000L && millisec <= 480000L)
        num3 = (byte)20;
    else if (millisec < 240000L)
        num3 = (byte)40;
    try
    {
        score = Convert.ToInt32((int)num2 * (int)num1 * (int)num3);
    }
    catch
    {
        score=0;
    }

    Console.SetCursorPosition(Program.x, Program.y);
    Console.Write("Your Score was: " + score);
```

}`

> The error is CalculateScore & I can't find the mistake. this is a method is to work ou Help is nedeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified that the function will return a value of type `long`, but there is no return statement returning a value at the end of the function

You need to add

```
return score;
```

as `score` is the result of the calculation

Comment: Isn't this the same answer I provided?

Answer (score 2):

`private static long CalculateScore` expects a return value of type long, but your method does not return anything.

Add the following to the end of the method.

```
return score;
```

And you might want to change the return type to `int` or the score variable to `long`

```
private static int CalculateScore(byte chances, long millisec)
{
  int score; 
  byte num1;
```

Or

```
private static long CalculateScore(byte chances, long millisec)
{
  long score; 
  byte num1;
```

Comment: People. Thank you for help! I spend 10 bloody hours I couldn't find that little miss. Thanks in advance :) –